# How to query the Active Directory using a list of users in a text file for a specific attribute with PowerShell

Tags: powershell, filter, get-aduser

I'm somewhat basic to Powershell and use one-liner commands only to keep it short and basic.

I would like to do the following: I have a list of users in a text file in the form of `UserPrincipalName`. I'd like to query this list of users if their accounts are still active/enabled or not. To do so, I'm trying to run the following command, which just reveals nothing in the end (blank output):

```
gc .\users.txt | foreach {get-aduser -server "corp.xxx.com" 
   -f 'name -like "$_"' -properties *}| select displayname,enabled
```

As mentioned, the output is blank with no errors or whatsoever.
I read that aduser doesn't work with pipelines, but I need to find a solution.

Kindly request your support :)

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your use of single quotes in your filter is not allowing the expansion of the variable. **[Double-quotes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_quoting_rules?view=powershell-7.2#double-quoted-strings) should be wrapping the filter expression so as to allow the interpolation of the [automatic variable `$_`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_automatic_variables?view=powershell-7.2#_)**:

```
Get-ADUser -Filter "name -like '$_'" ...
```

[**Single-quoted strings**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_quoting_rules?view=powershell-7.2#single-quoted-strings):

> A string enclosed in single quotation marks is a verbatim string. The string is passed to the command exactly as you type it. No substitution is performed.

Also note, you mention in your question that the file has the user's [`UserPrincipalName` attribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/adschema/a-userprincipalname), yet you're querying the [`Name` attribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/adschema/a-name), if that's the case, the filter should be:

```
Get-ADUser -Filter "UserPrincipalName -eq '$_'" ...
```

Note the use of `-eq` instead of `-like`, for exact matches you should always use this operator, see [**about_ActiveDirectory_Filter**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/server/hh531527(v=ws.10)) for usage details and examples of each operator.

If you're only interested in `DisplayName` and `Enabled` for your output, there is no reason in querying **all the user's attributes**, `-Properties *` should be just `-Properties DisplayName` since `Enabled` is already part of the default attributes returned by `Get-ADUser`.

Finally, the `-Identity` parameter can be bound from pipeline, and this parameter accepts a `UserPrincipalName` as argument, hence `ForEach-Object` is not needed in this case:

```
Get-Content .\users.txt |
    Get-ADUser -server "corp.xxx.com" -Properties DisplayName |
        Select-Object DisplayName, Enabled
```

Comment: Amazing, just by merely replacing the quotes with double quotes, it worked!
Thanks very much, lessons learned!

Comment: PS: yes, I surely changed from 'name' --> 'userprincipalname', that was a typo from my part :)